# Adding expiry to temporary links

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

i want to add an expiry time for links

sending them links then giving them only 1 day to access it. How can I do this in JavaScript?

I expect the output will be sending sending temporary links

Comment: you'd do it with *code* most likely on the *server*, because only the server can treat a link as current or not

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and explain in your question what exactly you are trying to do--links to what, how you intend for the server to deliver them, etc.

Comment: What links are you wanting to send? Drive links? Document share links? Any generic URL? If it's generic then what is your development environment? Do you have a web server? There is a lot of missing information from your question, please read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and update your question with as much information as you can which is relevant and helpful.

Comment: Also check out [how to create a Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you're stuck on some code that you can't get to work. Stackoverflow is not a source for people to write and produce code for you, but a discussion forum designed to help a community solve programming-related issues.